# JAVA: Adding a tron/worm like trail that can only be 6 units long

Tags: java, android

I am making a 9x9 grid type game for android. What I am wanting to accomplish is making a wall appear behind the player when they click on a button. This wall would start 0 units long and increased as the player moved on a button, going to 6 units. After it reaches this point, The wall should stay 6 units long, but the extra blocks on the end should disappear. I am new to programming so any help would be nice.

It would look like this

0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0

1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0

1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0

0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0

0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0

This would transition to the one below if they moved 1 space right.

0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0

0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0

1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0

0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0

0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2

0's are empty, 1 is wall, and 2 is player.

Any help would be nice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time the player moves you could add the previous tile (The one the player moved from) to the beginning of a list and set it's value to 1, then remove the last tile in the list and set its value back to 0.

So this would be the sequence of events whenever the player moves:

1. Set the current tile's value to 1
2. Add the current tile to the beginning of the list
3. Move the player to the new tile
4. Set the player's new current tile to a value of 2
5. If the list has less than or equal to 6 tiles then stop now, if not, carrying onto step 6
6. Set the value of the last tile in the list to 0
7. Remove the last tile from the list